# Arduino - delay() function vs. c - usleep() function

Tags: arduino

Is `delay(x)` the equivalent of `usleep(x*1000)`?

If this is true, then why is there a distinction, since "Processing" can execute "C"?

Comment: Interesting link concerning delay alternatives: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing can execute C, but the Arduino only contains a subset of the C library. Apparently usleep [is not included](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,42638.0.html).

[This link](https://groups.google.com/a/arduino.cc/forum/#!topic/developers/Bm5CaxtpQV0) seems to suggest that the implementation of delay and delayMicroseconds are designed specifically for the Arduino crystal and processor.

Answer (score 0):

usleep() is common in Linux and some others, but not for Aruduino.   DelayMicroseconds() is the typical arduino way to do this.   In the Linux context, usleep() yields to the scheduler, allowing othe processes and threads to run, which is often helpful.

Be advised that delayMicroseconds() accepts an unsigned short, and the documentation indicates it will not work as expected for values greater than 16383.  So any value over 16 milliseconds should use delay().  Another possibility is  to create a loop using micros():

```
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long delayTime = 21500; //   21.5 mSec 

startTime = micros();

while ( micros() - startTime < delayTime) {
  // do something useful, or not
}
```

This should work as long as delayTime is less than 70 minutes.  The calculation ***micros() - startTime*** may look suspicious -- what if this code is entered just before the overflow of micros() and the delay is just after?  Even if micros() returns a number smaller than startTime, the arithmetic underflow will still result in a number that is the proper difference in time.